# Centre images in Nivo Slider

Tags: css, nivo-slider

I have a Nivo Slider on my website, please see code below:

```
<!-- SLIDER START -->
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
            <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="slider/images/image.jpg" />
            </div>
<!-- SLIDER END -->

/*===================*/
/*=== Main Styles ===*/
/*===================*/
.theme-default #slider {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 100%; /* Make sure your images are the same size */
    height: 400px; /* Make sure your images are the same size */
}
.theme-pascal.slider-wrapper,
.theme-orman.slider-wrapper {
    margin-top:35px;
}
```

As you can see the width of the actual slider is 100% so it will always fit the width of the window.

some of the images are not going to be the same width as the users window as it is 100% but i cannot get the images in the slider to center for some reason.

i have done margin: 0 auto 0 auto; to try and make it centre but still nothing

any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `text-align:center;` rather than `margin:0 auto;` in your `.theme-default #slider` declaration if you want to center that `<img>`.